# How to get Firebase database saved data according to date?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, data-retrieval

I stored my data on Firebase according to auto-created ID. But now I need to get only today's added data from the database and populate a recycle view with it.[image]

Comment: you should store that date time

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your database doesn't contain information about the time the node was created, so it'll be hard to query for that. Unless you want to parse the key generated by `push()`, which I'd highly recommend against. Instead: store the date/timestamp into each node in a queryable format, and then use that to query against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume branch `users` storing users information. You can add child event listener to branch `users` to get users as follows in your activity or fragment.

```
private ArrayList<User> userArray = new ArrayList<>();
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getChild("users");

ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        if(user.getDate().equals(today)){
           userArray .add(user);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
       //do somethings
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
       //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
       //...
    }
};
```

Inside activity/fragment method, add the listener to your reference:

```
ref.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

The array will be filled out with data from branch `users`.
For more information how to work with list in firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Answer (score 0):

1. Start storing date time (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp)
2. Firebase database does not have querying capabilities, you should consider using Firestore.
3. Store records in groups like datatime>id>object. So when you want to get data for specific date all you need to do is ref('desireddatetime')
4. Brute Force (Not Recommended) Get the entire snapshot in one go and locally filter for date

Note - Calling push() will generate a uid key for you.
Instead you use child(), you can determine they key/path yourself.